# Extending __str__() rather than replacing it

Tags: python, python-2.4

I want to extend the `__str__()` method of my object.  The `str(obj)` currently reads:

```
<mymodule.Test object at 0x2b1f5098f2d0>
```

I like the address as a unique identifier, but I want to add some attributes.  What's the best way to extend this while still keeping the address portion?  I'd like to look something like this:

```
<mymodule.Test object at 0x2b1f5098f2d: name=foo, isValid=true>
```

I dont' see any attribute that stores the address.  I'm using python 2.4.3.

**Edit**: Would be nice to know how to do this with __repr__()

**Solution** (for python 2.4.3):

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<%s.%s object at %s, name=%s, isValid=%s>" % (self.__module__,
           self.__class__.__name__, hex(id(self)), self.name, self.isValid)
```

Comment: First of all, don't use such an outdated python version. Besides that, for what you are trying to do there's `__repr__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the address with `id(obj)`. You probably want to change the `__repr__()` method instead of `__str__()`. Here's code that will do this in Python 2.6+:

```
class Test(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        repr_template = ("<{0.__class__.__module__}.{0.__class__.__name__}"
                         " object at {1}: name={0.name}, isValid={0.isValid}>")

        return repr_template.format(self, hex(id(self)))
```

Test 
with:

```
test = Test()
test.name = "foo"
test.isValid = True
print repr(test)
print str(test)
print test
```

You could easily do the same sort of thing in an older version of Python by using string formatting operations like `"%s"` instead of the clearer `str.format()` syntax. If you are going to use `str.format()`, you can also use its built-in hex formatting capability by using `{1:#x}` in the template and changing argument 1 from `hex(id(self))` to simply `id(self)`.

Comment: What about the rest?  I see that obj.__class__.__name__ will return Test, but what about the module name?

Comment: Edited to have a complete answer.

Comment: That did it.  I just had to use the %s as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Mine(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return object.__str__(self) + " own attributes..."
```

Comment: This will not produce the output he desires. He wants it all to be in the angle-brackets in his example. This will return the original which is in it's own set of angle-brackets and adding his attributes "outside" of them.